# Matlab : getrect alternative?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking to select an area of an image in matlab using the mouse, returning the x/y of the corners to the user.

Looking online, the getrect function in the image processing toolbox does exactly this however I don't have the image processing toolbox.

Is the an open source alternative i.e. on matlab file exchange?

Mark

Comment: Look into `ginput` that will get you the vertices and then you need to connect them to create a poly mask.

Comment: I've tried ginput but as far as in know, you'd need to click the various vertices. I'm looking to drag a box across the image and return the xy coordinates.

Comment: and that without IP toolbox? Interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are okay using global variables and callbacks, then the following will probably do.  Create a function that passes (for example) the image that you wish to display

```
function extractblock(I)

    % clear all global variables (or just those specific to this app)
    clear GLOBAL;

    % display the image
    figure;
    image(I);

    % set callbacks for the handling of the mouse button down, motion, and
    % up events against this figure
    set(gcf,'WindowButtonDownFcn',   @myButtonDownCallback, ...
            'WindowButtonUpFcn',     @myButtonUpCallback,   ...
            'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @myButtonMotionCallback);
end
```

Now define the callbacks.  Start with the mouse button down event which will just record that the mouse button has been pressed and its position (this callback and the others can all be placed in the same file as the above function):

```
function myButtonDownCallback(~,~)

    global IS_BUTTON_DOWN;
    global RECT_START_COORD;

    IS_BUTTON_DOWN   = true;

    % get top left corner of rectangle
    RECT_START_COORD = get(gca,'CurrentPoint'); 
end
```

Now handle the mouse motion with a callback that will draw (or re-draw) the rectangle as the user moves the mouse pointer across the image:

```
function myButtonMotionCallback(~,~)

    global IS_BUTTON_DOWN;
    global RECT_START_COORD;
    global RECT_END_COORD;
    global RECTANGLE_HANDLE;

    if ~isempty(IS_BUTTON_DOWN) && IS_BUTTON_DOWN

        % get bottom right corner of rectangle
        RECT_END_COORD = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');

        % get the top left corner and width and height of 
        % rectangle (note the absolute value forces it to "open"
        % from left to right - need smarter logic for other direction)
        x = RECT_START_COORD(1,1);
        y = RECT_START_COORD(1,2);
        w = abs(x-RECT_END_COORD(1,1));
        h = abs(y-RECT_END_COORD(1,2));

        % only draw the rectangle if the width and height are positive
        if w>0 && h>0

            % rectangle drawn in white (better colour needed for different
            % images?)
            if isempty(RECTANGLE_HANDLE)
                % empty so rectangle not yet drawn
                RECTANGLE_HANDLE = rectangle('Position',[x,y,w,h],'EdgeColor','w');
            else
                % need to redraw
                set(RECTANGLE_HANDLE,'Position',[x,y,w,h],'EdgeColor','w');
            end
        end
    end  
end
```

Now handle the mouse up event which will remove the rectangle from the figure and write out the corners of the rectangle to the command window (means to return a matrix of some kind would have to be added if a return value is desired):

```
function myButtonUpCallback(~,~)

    global IS_BUTTON_DOWN;
    global RECTANGLE_HANDLE;
    global RECT_START_COORD;
    global RECT_END_COORD;

    % reset the button down flag
    IS_BUTTON_DOWN = false;

    % delete the rectangle from the figure
    delete(RECTANGLE_HANDLE);

    % clear the handle
    RECTANGLE_HANDLE = [];

    % compute the top left (tl) and bottom right (br) coordinates
    tl = [RECT_START_COORD(1,1)  RECT_START_COORD(1,2)];
    br = [RECT_END_COORD(1,1)    RECT_END_COORD(1,2)];

    % compute the top right (tr) and bottom left (bl) coordinates
    tr = [br(1)  tl(2)];
    bl = [tl(1)  br(2)];

    % write coordinates to command window
    fprintf('(%f,%f)\t',tl(1),tl(2));
    fprintf('(%f,%f)\n',tr(1),tr(2));
    fprintf('(%f,%f)\t',bl(1),bl(2));
    fprintf('(%f,%f)\n',br(1),br(2));
    fprintf('\n');

    % optionally display the block from the image
end
```

The above is quick way to extract a user-defined block from an image, with some logic missing to handle the rectangle being drawn from right to left.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Geoff!! That's brilliant! Cheers for your help